# How to disable caching of remote scripts and stylesheets when executing node-webkit based applications?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, node-webkit

I'm using node-webkit to create a desktop application from an intranet site with a lot of external scripts and stylesheets.  An issue I've noticed when debugging is that it seems to cache the external scripts and stylesheets sporadically between different runs - sometimes it will load a recently modified script and other times it will not without turning on the addressbar and typing the script path in manually then hitting reload.  Is there any way to make it so every time it loads it is getting a fresh copy of the dependencies?

The package.json I'm using is below:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description",
    "version": "0.1",
    "main": "https://path-to-intranet-site/",
    "node-remote": "https://path-to-intranet-site",
    "window": {
        "show": true,
        "toolbar": true,
        "frame": true,
        "position": "center",
        "width": 800,
        "height": 600,
        "min_width": 220,
        "min_height": 220
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to edit package.json  as follow:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description",
    "version": "0.1",
    "main": "https://path-to-intranet-site/",
    "node-remote": "https://path-to-intranet-site",
    "webkit": {
         "page-cache":false
    },
    "window": {
        "show": true,
        "toolbar": true,
        "frame": true,
        "position": "center",
        "width": 800,
        "height": 600,
        "min_width": 220,
        "min_height": 220
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of [Manifest format](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Manifest-format) page-cache by default is false in the [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/) wiki page.

Search in page for page-cache is is a little down.